# Как происходит сортировка в MySQL с помощью ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

Сортировка в не сколько столбцов происходит же таким образом :

> Сначала сортируется указанный столбец,потом второй и т.д.
>   ORDER BY ... , ... , ...

Есть таблица :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сортирую результат запроса таким образом :

```
SELECT * FROM `dogs` ORDER BY NickName , Breed;
```

Вопрос,почему у меня получается так :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала сортируется по NickName , в итоге Frolov станет на первое место,но когда будет сортироваться по Breed,то Danyil первый должен стоять,нежели Nikita
Но,почему-то Nikita Стоит первый.Подскажите пожалуйста,почему так?

Comment: сортировка по второму столбцу актуальна для одинаковых значений в превом столбце. иначе бы в первой колонке не было бы никакого смысла

Comment: Да,логично..Огромное вам спасибо